# pass value from promise to promise with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to pass an object that I build piece by piece with promises using firebase. I don't really need the object to be passed along the promise chain if there is a better way to construct the object step by step. Here is my code:

```
    var queue = new Queue(productUpdateQueue, function(data, progress, resolve, reject) {

    var incomingUpdateData = data;
    var receiptID = incomingUpdateData.receiptID;
    var userID = incomingUpdateData.userID;
    var oldProductID = incomingUpdateData.oldProductID;
    var newProductID = incomingUpdateData.newProductID;
    var newReceipt = incomingUpdateData.newReceipt;

    var postID = "";

    var updateObject = {};

    updateObject['usersPrivate/'+userID+'/receipts/'+receiptID+'/items/'+oldProductID] = null;
    updateObject['usersPrivate/'+userID+'/receipts/'+receiptID+'/items/'+newProductID] = newReceipt;

    clicks.child('VigLink').orderByChild('item').equalTo(oldProductID).once('value', function(cuidSnapshot) {
        return cuidSnapshot.forEach(function(cuidSnapshot) {
            var cuid = cuidSnapshot.key;
            updateObject['clicks/VigLink/'+cuid+'/item'] = newProductID;
            console.log('one');
            progress(20);
        });
    }).then(function() {
        return userReceiptMetrics.child(userID).child('receipts').child(receiptID).child('items').child(oldProductID).once('value', function(oldSnapshot) {
            var data = oldSnapshot.val()
            updateObject['userReceiptMetrics/'+userID+'/receipts/'+receiptID+'/items/'+oldProductID] = null
            updateObject['userReceiptMetrics/'+userID+'/receipts/'+receiptID+'/items/'+newProductID] = data
            if (data != null) {
                updateObject['userReceiptMetrics/'+userID+'/receipts/'+receiptID+'/itemIDs/'+newProductID] = now
                updateObject['userReceiptMetrics/'+userID+'/receipts/'+receiptID+'/itemIDs/'+oldProductID] = null
            };
            console.log('two');
            progress(40);
        });
    }).then(function() {
        return userReceiptMetrics.child(userID).child('shops').child(oldProductID).once('value', function(oldSnapshot) {
            var data = oldSnapshot.val()
            updateObject['userReceiptMetrics/'+userID+'/shops/'+oldProductID] = null;
            updateObject['userReceiptMetrics/'+userID+'/shops/'+newProductID] = data;
            if (data != null) {
                updateObject['userReceiptMetrics/'+userID+'/shopIDs/'+newProductID] = now;
                updateObject['userReceiptMetrics/'+userID+'/shopIDs/'+oldProductID] = null;
            };
            console.log('three');
            progress(60);
        });
    }).then(function() {
        return posts.once('value', function(postSnapshot) {
            // use Promise.all and Array#map to wait for all these queries to finish

            var allPosts = postSnapshot.val()
            var postKeys = Object.keys(allPosts)

            return Promise.all(postKeys.map(function(postKey) {
                var postID = postKey;

                return posts.child(postID).child('items').child(oldProductID).once('value', function(itemSnapshot) {

                    itemSnapshot.forEach(function(itemSnapshot) {
                        var itemData = itemSnapshot.val()
                        console.log('post snapshot'+ itemSnapshot);
                        updateObject['posts/'+postID+'/items/'+oldProductID] = null
                        updateObject['posts/'+postID+'/items/'+newProductID] = itemData
                    });
                });
            })).then(function(results) {
                // put progress update in .then, and return the results 
                progress(75);
                return results;
            });
        });
    }).then(function() {
        // Move to next item
        return console.log('hey look here'+updateObject['posts/'+postID+'/items/'+newProductID]);
        return firebaseRoot.update(updateObject, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error updating data:", error);
                reject()
            } else {
                progress(100);
                // resolve();
                console.log('four');
            }
        });
    });

    // Finish the task asynchronously
    setTimeout(function() {
        reject();
    }, 10000);
});
```

And the output is:

```
one
two
three
hey look hereundefined
post snapshot[object Object]
post snapshot[object Object]
post snapshot[object Object]
post snapshot[object Object]
post snapshot[object Object]
post snapshot[object Object]
post snapshot[object Object]
post snapshot[object Object]
```

Any and all help is super appreciated.

Comment: Can you check whether execution actually enters the callback registered for the value event on the userReceiptMetrics.child(userID).child('receipts').child(receiptID).child('items').child(oldProductID) variable?

Comment: As I'm seeing it now, it never exits the first promise section. I am seeing the progress get set to 12 and then the server crashes.

Comment: So what makes you say it never exit the first promise? The error reported seems to point to the instructions trying to affect to  updateObject['userReceiptMetrics/'+userID+'/shops/'+oldProductID] which are further down the chain

Comment: Yeah, that's what I don't get. if I put a console.log() statement anywhere beyond the first promise, it doesn't get called. Also, I am watching it put data onto my firebase as it works (before it crashes) and it seems to be getting only to the part that sets the progress to 12 before crashing.

Comment: Really, I'm thinking that maybe ```return updateObject;``` doesn't pass the object to the next promise and so ```updateObject``` is undefined. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah, actually, you are only returning from the event handlers callbacks - not from the then() callbacks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130861/discussion-between-wikipediabrown-and-iamdranged).

Comment: `I am seeing the progress get set to 12 and then the server crashes` - as there is a return before **each** of the progress calls, I highly doubt you see any `progress` - though that wouldn't stop the progress

Comment: I'll put the whole error up in a second but progress is a parameter that forbase sets as your task is completed. I set it to 12 at in the first promise and it never got past that. I've been changing it in different ways to get it to complete but the problem is that each promise doesn't complete and then pass on its work in sequence.

Comment: at a guess, the promise returned by `once` has little to do with the value returned by the callback to `once` - but I can't find documentation on `once` so it's a guess - don't worry about the whole error message, it's obvious where it comes from :p

Comment: can you try declaring `var updateObject = {};` just below `var newReceipt` and remove `updateObject` from the callback functions of the .then's

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks about the error. I'm still trying to figure it out. What I've kind of found is that promises aren't as easy as they are portrayed.

Comment: Actually, ignore my previous comment, just remove the `updateObject` from the arguments of the .then function callbacks - i.e. they should all look like `}).then(function() {` ... it'd be easier if the documentation wasn't so damned hard to find

Comment: Ok so I updated the code how I think you're looking for it. The object only gets updated with the data from outside of the promise chain. Nothing inside of the promise chain is actually added to the object when I set it.

Comment: you're not chaining the promises correctly ... you need to `return userReceiptMetrics.child(userID) ...` and `return posts.orderByChild('items') ...` etc - you'll need to move your progress calls too - something like https://jsfiddle.net/skvjz9qw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured out how to do this. I was having a problem passing the object from step to step but what I really wanted to do was create the object step by step. So I created the object outside of the promise chain and built it step by step. One of the main obstacles here was to get my loops to complete and then move on to the next promise in the chain. In order to do that, I used `Promise.all()` to return the results.

It works and now I know more about how promises work. If this can help you please take it:

```
var queue = new Queue(productUpdateQueue, function(data, progress, resolve, reject) {

    var incomingUpdateData = data;
    var receiptID = incomingUpdateData.receiptID;
    var userID = incomingUpdateData.userID;
    var oldProductID = incomingUpdateData.oldProductID;
    var newProductID = incomingUpdateData.newProductID;
    var newReceipt = incomingUpdateData.newReceipt;

    var postID = "-KZOO0UII67uOmYo6DJh";

    var postKeys = [];

    var updateObject = {};

    updateObject['usersPrivate/'+userID+'/receipts/'+receiptID+'/items/'+oldProductID] = null;
    updateObject['usersPrivate/'+userID+'/receipts/'+receiptID+'/items/'+newProductID] = newReceipt;

    return clicks.child('VigLink').orderByChild('item').equalTo(oldProductID).once('value', function(cuidSnapshot) {
        return cuidSnapshot.forEach(function(cuidSnapshot) {
            var cuid = cuidSnapshot.key;
            updateObject['clicks/VigLink/'+cuid+'/item'] = newProductID;
            progress(10);
        });
    }).then(function() {
        return userReceiptMetrics.child(userID).child('receipts').child(receiptID).child('items').child(oldProductID).once('value', function(oldSnapshot) {
            var data = oldSnapshot.val()
            updateObject['userReceiptMetrics/'+userID+'/receipts/'+receiptID+'/items/'+oldProductID] = null
            updateObject['userReceiptMetrics/'+userID+'/receipts/'+receiptID+'/items/'+newProductID] = data
            if (data != null) {
                updateObject['userReceiptMetrics/'+userID+'/receipts/'+receiptID+'/itemIDs/'+newProductID] = now
                updateObject['userReceiptMetrics/'+userID+'/receipts/'+receiptID+'/itemIDs/'+oldProductID] = null
            };
            progress(25);
        });
    }).then(function() {
        return userReceiptMetrics.child(userID).child('shops').child(oldProductID).once('value', function(oldSnapshot) {
            var data = oldSnapshot.val()
            updateObject['userReceiptMetrics/'+userID+'/shops/'+oldProductID] = null;
            updateObject['userReceiptMetrics/'+userID+'/shops/'+newProductID] = data;
            if (data != null) {
                updateObject['userReceiptMetrics/'+userID+'/shopIDs/'+newProductID] = now;
                updateObject['userReceiptMetrics/'+userID+'/shopIDs/'+oldProductID] = null;
            };
            progress(40);
        });
    }).then(function() {
        progress(55);
        return posts.orderByChild('receipt').equalTo(receiptID).once('value');
    }).then(function(postSnapshot) {
        return postSnapshot.forEach(function(post) {
            progress(70);
            postKeys.push(post.key)
        });
    }).then(function() {
        return Promise.all(postKeys.map(function(postKey) {
            return posts.child(postKey).child('items').child(oldProductID).once('value', function(itemSnapshot) {
                var itemData = itemSnapshot.val()
                updateObject['posts/'+postKey+'/items/'+oldProductID] = null;
                updateObject['posts/'+postKey+'/items/'+newProductID] = itemData;
            });
        })).then(function(results) {
            progress(85);
            return results;
        });
    }).then(function() {
        return firebaseRoot.update(updateObject, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error updating data:", error);
                reject()
            } else {
                progress(100);
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });

    // Finish the task asynchronously
    setTimeout(function() {
        reject();
    }, 10000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your .then from (now changed in the question, but the code originally had this)

```
}).then(function(updateObject) {
```

to

```
}).then(function() {
```

So that your code always updates the updateObject declared in the `new Queue` callback

also, the first line in each then needs to have a return added

so, instead of

```
userReceiptMetrics.child(userID).child('receipts').child(receiptID).child('items').child(oldProductID).once('value', function(oldSnapshot) {
```

you have

```
return userReceiptMetrics.child(userID).child('receipts').child(receiptID).child('items').child(oldProductID).once('value', function(oldSnapshot) {
```

The progress calls need to be put at the end of the .once callbacks

over all, the code should look like (removed most of the code that's correct, hope this is understandable

```
var queue = new Queue(productUpdateQueue, function(data, progress, resolve, reject) {
    // removed for brevity
    var updateObject = {};
    // removed for brevity
    clicks.child('VigLink').orderByChild('item').equalTo(oldProductID).once('value', function(cuidSnapshot) {
        // removed for brevity
        progress(12);
    }).then(function() {
        return userReceiptMetrics.child(userID).child('receipts').child(receiptID).child('items').child(oldProductID).once('value', function(oldSnapshot) {
            // removed for brevity
            progress(25);
        });
    }).then(function() {
        return userReceiptMetrics.child(userID).child('shops').child(oldProductID).once('value', function(oldSnapshot) {
            // removed for brevity
            progress(50);
        });
    }).then(function() {
        return posts.orderByChild('items').equalTo(oldProductID).once('value', function(postSnapshot) {
            // use Promise.all and Array#map to wait for all these queries to finish
            return Promise.all(postSnapshot.map(function(postSnapshot) {
                var postID = postSnapshot.key;

                return posts.child(postID).child('items').child(oldProductID).once('value', function(itemSnapshot) {

                    itemSnapshot.forEach(function(itemSnapshot) {
                        var itemData = itemSnapshot.val()

                        updateObject['posts/'+postID+'/items/'+oldProductID] = null
                        updateObject['posts/'+postID+'/items/'+newProductID] = itemData
                    });
                });
            })).then(function(results) {
                // put progress update in .then, and return the results 
                progress(75);
                return results;
            });
        });
    }).then(function() {
        // Move to next item
        console.log(updateObject);
        // removed for brevity
    });

    // Finish the task asynchronously
    setTimeout(function() {
        reject();
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a billion Jaromanda X!! I'm pretty sure that they promises are happening sequentially and that I am doing something else wrong before I set the objects on Firebase. You're help was super helpful and because of that I award you this Saturday's 'g' award. You are officially a g.

Comment: Ok. So it looks like this is working except for one problem. the two loops that I am using both finish after the entire promise chain ends. Can you not use loops in promises?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the forEach loops were also using asynch code - let me amend the answer

Comment: I've edited the answer with (hopefully) correct code for that one section that uses asynch inside forEach - it uses Promise.all and Array#map to wait for all the inner queries to resolve

Comment: it's telling me that ```.map is not a function```

Comment: that would suggest `postSnapshot` is not an actual Array

Comment: So after looking into it, it seems that it is not an array but an object with a bunch of objects in it. Am I approaching this wrong?